# Set Parameters from User Input

Tags: entries, form, ordering

Is there a way to set parameters from front-end user input?

Let's say I have a page that displays a list of entries. On that page, I have a form select called `paidStatus` with options `notReceived`, `received`, and `paid`; and another form select called `order` with options `asc` and `desc`.

Then, in my template code, I want to grab the list of entries:

`{% for entry in craft.entries.section('sectionName').order('postDate post.order').find() if entry.paidStatus == post.paidStatus %}`

with `order` and `entryStatus` being populated from the submitted form selects. That way I can change the criteria used to generate the list of entries on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass in a variable into the parameters and to get the query string values use `craft.request.getQuery()`.

I can recommend this blog post by Jérôme Coupé for a great introduction to setting up the form and the criteria model filters:

[Combined searches and filters using Craft](http://webstoemp.com/blog/combined-searches-and-filters-craft-cms/)

You should also have a look at other questions tagged with "form".